# how can i make a method during for few seconds when i press a key?

Tags: c#, xna

I want to make an animation during 2 seconds after pressing a key.
For example i want to load an animation for shooting and I want it to take 2 seconds only, after it will turn back to "stay" animation.

```
class Player
{
PlayerAnimation animation;
Animation walk;
Animation stay;
Animation jump;;
public Vector2 position;
public Vector2 velocity;
public Rectangle rect;
public bool jumping = false;
public int health = 5;
public Vector2 Position{ get { return position; } }


public Player() { }

public void Load(ContentManager Content) {

    walk = new Animation(Content.Load<Texture2D>("walk"), 46, 0.1f, true, rect);
    animazioneMinima = new Animation(Content.Load<Texture2D>("stay"),37, 0.15f, true, rect);
    jump = new Animation(Content.Load<Texture2D>("jump"), 51, 0.1f, true , rect);


}

public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    position += velocity;
    rect = new Rectangle((int)position.X, (int)position.Y, 43, 46);
    Input(gameTime);



    if (velocity.X != 0)
        PlayerAnimation.PlayAnimation(walk);

    else if (velocity.X == 0)
        PlayerAnimation.PlayAnimation(stay;
    if (velocity.Y < 10)
        velocity.Y += 0.4f;
}


private void Input(GameTime gameTime)
{
    if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
        velocity.X = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds / 3;
    else if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
        velocity.X = -(float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds / 3;
    else velocity.X = 0f;


    if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Space) && jumping == false)
    {
        position.Y -= 5f;
        velocity.Y = -9f;
        jumping = true;
    }

}


public void Draw(GameTime gameTime, SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
{
    SpriteEffects rotate = SpriteEffects.None;

    if (velocity.X >= 0)
        rotate = SpriteEffects.None;
    else if (velocity.X < 0)
        rotate = SpriteEffects.FlipHorizontally;

    PlayerAnimation.Draw(gameTime, spriteBatch, position, rotate);
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `GameTime` that is passed to you via the method arguments, the common solution is to "save" the starting `GameTime` and each game loop iteration check the difference:

```
private GameTime animGameTimeStart;
public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    //When starting the animation:
    this.animGameTimeStart = gameTime;

    if(gameTime.ElapsedTime - animGameTimeStart.ElapsedTime <= TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2))
    { 
        //Set again to Idle
    }
}
```